# Julia extract Polynomial coefficients as Vector

Tags: vector, julia, polynomials

How do I extract the coefficients of a Julia `Polynomial`?

In Julia we can create a `Polynomial`:

```
using Polynomials
p = Polynomial([23,34,23,135])
```

Which gives:

```
Polynomial(23 + 34*x + 23*x^2 + 135*x^3)
```

How do I extract the coefficients and store them in a `Vector`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Julia`, this is done using the `coeffs()` function.

For the above `Polynomial` called `p`, this is done as such:

```
coeffs(p)
```

Which gives:

```
4-element Vector{Int64}:
  23
  34
  23
 135
```

Comment: If you're satisfied with the answer, you can mark this as accepted so that this doesn't show up as an "unanswered question".